# How to get other member discord id?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, discord, discord.js, mongoose-schema

i want to make command that can give me information about someone that i mention like `!info @Someone` i try code below, but didnt work.

This is the schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const profileSchema = new Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    userID: String,
    nickname: String,
    ar: Number,
    server: String,
    uid: Number,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", profileSchema);
```

and this is what i try, but show nothing, didnt show any error sign.

```
client.on("message", async msg => {
  let member = msg.mentions.users.first().username
  if (msg.content === `!info @${member}`){ 
    userData = await User.findOne({userID : msg.mentions.users.first().id});
     if (userData) {
        const exampleEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#808080')
        .setTitle('Data Member')
        .setDescription(`**Nickname :** ${userData.nickname}\n**Adventure Rank :** ${userData.ar}\nServer: ${userData.server}\n**User ID :** ${userData.uid}`)
        .setThumbnail(msg.author.avatarURL())
        msg.reply({ embeds: [exampleEmbed] });
     } else{
      msg.reply("Please registration first")
     }
  }
}
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By seeing your code, it might shuffle all of your `.first()` lets modify your code.

```
client.on("message", async msg => {
let member = msg.mentions.members.first() || msg.guild.members.fetch(args[0]); //You can also use their ID by using these
if (msg.content === `!info ${member.username || member.user.username}`) { //then adding the user.username
const userData = await User.findOne({
  userID: member.id || member.user.id //same as here
}); //userData shows as "any" so you need to change it to const userData
if (userData) {
  const exampleEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#808080')
    .setTitle('Data Member')
    .setDescription(`**Nickname :** ${userData.nickname}\n**Adventure Rank :** ${userData.ar}\nServer: ${userData.server}\n**User ID :** ${userData.uid}`)
    .setThumbnail(msg.author.avatarURL())
  msg.reply({
    embeds: [exampleEmbed]
  });
} else {
  msg.reply("Please registration first")
}
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `if` condition. [How Discord Mentions Work](https://discordjs.guide/miscellaneous/parsing-mention-arguments.html#how-discord-mentions-work)

> Discord uses a special syntax to embed mentions in a message. For user mentions, it is the user's ID with <@ at the start and > at the end, like this: <@86890631690977280>.

```
if (msg.content === `!info ${message.mentions.users.first()}`)
```

For example:

```
const member = msg.mentions.users.first();
if (msg.content === `!info ${member}`){ 
    User.findOne({ userID: member.id }, (err, user) => {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        if (!user) return msg.reply("User not found");
        console.log(user);
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Going through your code, I found these errors.

first of all you need members not users in `message.mentions.members.first()`.

Second of all, you need to define `UserData` first like `const UserData = ...`

```js
client.on("message", async msg => {
  let member = msg.mentions.members.first()
  if (msg.content === `!info @${member}`){ 
    User.findOne({userID : member.id}, async (err, userData) => {
     if (userData) {
        const exampleEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#808080')
        .setTitle('Data Member')
        .setDescription(`**Nickname :** ${userData.nickname}\n**Adventure Rank :** ${userData.ar}\nServer: ${userData.server}\n**User ID :** ${userData.uid}`)
        .setThumbnail(msg.author.avatarURL())
        msg.reply({ embeds: [exampleEmbed] });
     } else{
      msg.reply("Please registration first")
     }
  }
 });
});
```

Let me know if it works after fixing these errors.
Also `message` event is depricated so try using `MessageCreate` instead from now on

Comment: Still nothing happen ?

Comment: try `User.findOne({userID : member.id}, async (err, userData) => {'Your code here'})` check My edited post

Comment: still didnt show anything

Comment: Can you edit your post to the new updated and fixed code

Comment: I use same as ur code

Comment: By using `message.mentions.members.first()`, you are getting a [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildMember). A `GuildMember` doesn't have the `username` property, so that would be undefined

Comment: They are getting the `nickname` from the database, not from the GuildMember. UserData is the database collection var and nickname is an item in this collection.

Comment: @Christy, but you're using `let member = msg.mentions.members.first().username` and it's `undefined`. Use `let member = msg.mentions.members.first().user.username` or `let member = msg.mentions.users.first().username` instead.

Comment: Ahhh @yessir my bad I copy pasted the code and did not see this problem and up in my answer I did not use `.username` so I obviously did not see it in the code! Sorry!